# How to list all open ports after blocking ports using iptables?

Tags: linux, security, iptables

I use these commands to block all ports and allow only some specific ports.

```
iptables -F  
iptables -X  
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT  
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT  
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT  
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE    
iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT    
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT  
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT    
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT  
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT  
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT  
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 443 -j ACCEPT    
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT  
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 1723 -j ACCEPT    
iptables -A INPUT -p gre -j ACCEPT      
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP  
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

This uses iptables to block all ports except 80, 22, 443, 1723.

What command can I use to check which ports are open?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `nmap`.

For example :

```bsh
nmap -p 1-65535  127.0.0.1
```

will find all open ports in the range `1` to `65535`. That last number is the maximum a port can have.

Comment: But i open only 4 ports, all other ports are blocked.  the output of command you gave me, shows so many ports.

Comment: @PurvalPatel You have `lo` wide open, so anything on 127.0.0.1 _will_ go through. Try the same command on a different machine, replacing the loopback address with the IP of the machine running `iptables`